# Scikit-Learn: how to print out details from mis-classified records array?

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn, classification

Having run a scikit-learn classifier on a train / test dataset and got the confusion matrix, I am trying to print out the array of 28 misclassified records. A 'for' loop doesn't seem to work! Here's what I'm doing:

```
y_test = np.asarray(y_test)
misclassified = np.where(y_test != my_email_classifier.predict(X_test))

misclassified
```

produces this output:

```
(array([  17,  232,  278,  362,  366,  395,  538,  576,  674,  699,  716,
         749,  787,  929,  983, 1015, 1020, 1077, 1154, 1157, 1201, 1301,
        1338, 1399, 1444, 1451, 1612, 1666], dtype=int64),)
```

which are the correct row indexes.

This line:

```
print(misclassified[0][0], y[misclassified[0][0]], n[misclassified[0][0]])
```

produces the output:

```
17 phish 113.txt
```

and this ties back to the correct dataframe message.
But when I try to put this print statement in a 'for' loop to print out the full list of the misclassified array as so:

```
i=0
for x in misclassified:
    print(x[0][i], y[x[0][i]], n[x[0][i]])
    i+=1
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-9a038043ab65> in <module>
      1 i=0
      2 for x in misclassified:
----> 3     print(x[0][i], y[x[0][i]], n[x[0][i]])
      4     i+=1

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Comment: What is your goal? `x in misclassified` are single numbers, therefore you can't iterate through them. `missclasified[0][0]` is not valid input for 1D array, I feel some trickery happened with your variables :)

Comment: Thanks for response. Sorry, but I don't understand what you have related here.